# Issues connecting to Oracle server via Oracle Instant Client. When to use 32bit vs 64bit?

Tags: windows, oracle, 32bit-64bit, oracle-call-interface, devart

I have issues to connect to ***Oracle Server (10g) 32bit*** running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64), from a remote computer using ***Oracle Instant Client (11.2.0.4) 64bit*** which runs Windows 10 Home (x64). 
The error message I get is **"Underlying provider failed on Open ... Can not obtain Oracle client information from registry"**

I have this web application, hosted under IIS, on 64bit AppPool loading the OCI to connect to Oracle Server.

Important to note here, that I managed to have it working by using ***Oracle Instant Client (11.2.0.4) 32bit*** , and changing the AppPool of IIS to 32bit.

**Can anybody explain why OCI 64bit does not work? Is it because the Oracle Server is 32bit and it must comply to this?**

---

**Update:**

I did not specify that I am using Devart libraries which in the end are looking for the "oci.dll", so the error is coming from there.

Comment: you had 'issues' - what exactly were the issues? you can make a 64 bit client connection to a 32 bit server running Oracle Database with no problems and vice versa

Comment: From my experience if you're using OCI you need 32bit client for 32bit server and 64bit client for 64bit server. I also wouldn't risk using client for 11 on server which is 10.

Comment: Thank you @Kacper for this. I didn't know they should match!

Comment: No. The _server_ version of Oracle is irrelevant here. It's all about the client. A 64 bit driver can connect to a 64 _or_ 32 bit version of Oracle server. The issue is that if you only have a 64 bit client driver installed, then the client using this (in your case IIS) must be 64 bit. That's why I always install both 32 and 64 bit versions of clients as this reduces this issue. I can't explain why your 64 bi client didn't work in this case but I can tell you the Windows Oracle client has lots of bugs and issues. I suggest you test the oracle ODBC driver using 32 and 64 bit ODBCAD.EXE

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, very useful information!

Comment: error says it can't get info from the Registry...the Instant Client doesn't write to the registry, b/c it's just a package you unzip vs INSTALL - is your other client a full client install vs an Instant Client?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Both 32 and 64bit are Instant Clients, as you said, just unzipped and added to ENV VARs (either one or the other)... But is good point, maybe in the end is about Devart libraries which look for the oci.dll... I will try to search more in this direction (I will update my question also)

Comment: check your path - the first instant client found in the path is what the apps will try to load